# Уточняющий оборот с ИЛИ

Tags: пунктуация, приложение, уточнения

Тире, запятая или запятая-тире?

Все большую известность стали приобретать люминиры, или ламинатные виниры (?) тонкие пластинки, располагающиеся на передней поверхности зуба и изготовленные из керамики или композита.

Comment: По кругу, по сторонам, по краю и по поверхности может нечто проходить, а не располагаться. Располагается НА поверхности.

Comment: Спасибо, исправила.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы знак тождества не относился только к уточнению, последнее следует отбить запятой. Такой же результат может дать обособление уточнения скобками.

*Всё большую известность стали приобретать люминиры, или ламинатные виниры, — тонкие пластинки, располагающиеся на передней поверхности зуба и изготовленные из керамики или композита.*

*Всё большую известность стали приобретать люминиры (ламинатные виниры) — тонкие пластинки из керамики или композита, располагающиеся на передней поверхности зуба.*

Вариант с одним причастием предпочтителен, а более него — совсем без причастий.

*Всё большую известность стали приобретать люминиры (ламинатные виниры) — тонкие пластинки из керамики или композита на передней поверхности зуба.*